# Create ribbon button Dynamically in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

Can any one help me to create a ribbon button dynamically in CRM 2011. The scenario is, when we create a record, one ribbon button has to be created dynamically based the optionset value selected in that record. Can we get it work using JScript or Plug-in or Workflow? Enable or Display rules are not useful here and should not touch XML code.

Comment: Why do you to avoid enable or disable rules? Do you basically just want a ribbon button that does something different depending on the record status?

Comment: Yes, the functionality is based on the value selected in optionset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get it done by two ways-

**Through plug-in:**(Note: It won't works in Sandbox mode and consume some time.)

- Create one solution and add specified entity to it. Go through the source code  [here](http://charanmandya.blogspot.in/2012/10/plug-in-to-create-solution-and-add.html)
- Export this solution to *Temp* folder and unzip it.
- Edit customizations.xml file to add our own RibbondiffXml tag.
- Zip all the XML files and Import it to CRM.
- Publish the Customization.

**Through XML edit:**

- Export Application Ribbon, update XML to add button and replace entity name with {!EntityLogicalName} in all the places. 
  Ex: `<CustomAction Id="New.{!EntityLogicalName}.MyButton.CustomAction" Location="Mscrm.HomepageGrid.{!EntityLogicalName}.MainTab.Management.Controls._children" Sequence="70">`...
- Add EnableRule to enable this button only if Config record exist for current entity.

  `<EnableRule Id="New.{!EntityLogicalName}.MyButton.Check">
    <CustomRule FunctionName="checkConfigRecord" Library="$webresource:new_/Scripts/ValidateConfigRecords.js">
      <CrmParameter Value="SelectedEntityTypeName" />
    </CustomRule>
  </EnableRule>`
- Create one JavaScript library with name *new_/Scripts/ValidateConfigRecords.js* which contains function *checkConfigRecord* which counts config records exists for particular entity. If count is greater than 1 return *true*. Otherwise *false*.
- Import the ApplicationRibbon Zipped file

Answer (score 3):

Quick principle: Ribbon Buttons are not a part the record, they are a part of the UI. You can make the UI change based on the record you are looking. Therefore you cannot 'add' a button to a record. You can add a button to an entity form.

Plugins definetly wont work here, they peform logic on the 'back-end'. JavaScript might work but I would expect this to be quite awkward. What you should do is edit the ribbon Xml. Now there is an excellent for editing the ribbon: [Ribbon Workbench](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx), this tool make it significantly easier to 
edit the ribbon (this is editing the XML but this is the way its meant to be done).

Then I think you will need to

1. Create a ribbon button for each action.
2. Then follow this tutorial to enable and disable them: [Enable/Disable a ribbon button dynamically based on a form value.](http://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/121427-enable-disable-a-ribbon-button-dynamically-based-o)

Answer (score 0):

Using a display rule would be the right way to do this.

Create multiple buttons and set their display rule when selected option is equal
to the button's name.

Comment: We need to do this action for all N entities.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on Dynamics 365 and found a solution.

RibbonWorkbench includes a feature called "Fly Out Anchor Buttons"

This includes a property called PopulateQueryCommand.

You can use this command to dynamically (using JScript) add menu options to the Anchor Buttons at runtime.

The RibbonWorkbench documentation includes all the information you need to use this feature.